# Error in Inserting data in SQL table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to insert data in a table (say feedback) with columns from(int) and Message(Varchar(MAX)) via c# code but it is continuously annoying me with errors. Please help, I am desperate.

Table description:
From int,Message Varchar(max)

### Code I'm using:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.open;
string query="insert into Feedback (From,Message) values(@frm,@msg)";
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@frm", Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxid.Text));
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msg",TextBoxFeedBack.text);

comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

The Error I'm getting is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near
>   the keyword 'From'. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   _Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Ajaz\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\WebSites\WebSite26\Default.aspx.cs:line 29

I'm guessing there's error related to data mismatch. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FROM` is a [*reserved keyword*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in TSQL. You should use it with square brackets like `[FROM]`

```
string query="insert into Feedback ([From],Message) values(@frm,@msg)";
```

As a general recomendation, don't use reserved keywords for your identifiers and object names in your database.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` like;

```
string query = "insert into Feedback ([From],Message) values(@frm,@msg)";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
  SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
  comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@frm", Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxid.Text));
  comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msg",TextBoxFeedBack.text);
  con.Open();
  comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"From" is the reserved word. Surround it by square brackets:

```
string query="insert into Feedback ([From],Message) values(@frm,@msg)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the word FROM is a well known keyword in any SQL language existing in the world. If you want to use it (very bad move) then you need to encapsulate it in square brackets

```
string query="insert into Feedback ([From],Message) values(@frm,@msg)";
```

Again, don't do that, change the name of the column before having to much code to change.
Otherwise you will have this problem for the lifetime of your app.